# How to range items in for loop?

Tags: python, html, django

I am fetching data from database by the name `field.title` and `field.img` in `views.py` and I made loop and gave range to it of 2 items but it is fetching every item from database. I use `__` in for loop range but whenever I use field in range it gives me `AttributeError`. Destination is a class in `models.py`

```
target1 = Destination.objects.all()
for field in target1:
    for __ in range(2):
        field.img
        field.title
```

Comment: You are looping through all the targets. The second loop isn't really doing anything as it simply repeats the same operation on every field in target

Comment: Even if the for loops succeeded, you aren't doing anything with the fields when you do get them

Comment: I didn't know what to use? Could you help me?

Comment: Its unclear what you are trying to do

Comment: What are you trying to do with `field.img` and `field.title`?

Comment: I just want to give range to it.

Comment: I am sure there is a way to limit your query to just 2 items like `fetchmany(2)` on a cursor object

Comment: I am fetching data from database by the name ```field.img``` and ```field.title``` and it is working but I want to give range to it instead of printing all.

Comment: It's still unclear

Comment: What does "give range to it" mean? [ask]

Comment: So are you saying you want the first 2 in `target1`?

Comment: How to use fetchmany(2) Buckeye

Comment: Sayse I want to limit the items. I don't want every item.

Comment: Could anyone help me instead of asking? I have explained everything. in question.

Comment: Try this [Limit Query Set](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what we can deduce, limiting your queryset (`target1` in this case) is what you may be looking for:

```
target1 = Destination.objects.all()[:2]
for field in target1:
    # do whatever it is that you need to do
    field.img
    field.title
```

You may need to check the ordering of your queryset so that you get the first two that you expect. Hope this helps.